# Analytics users flow for multiple properties

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I have several properties in Analytics. They are all different subdomains of my primary domain. For example, one.example.com, two,example.com, etc.

I want to know if there is a way to have a view, or a new property, or something that will allow me to use the 'users flow' chart under the audience tab for all my properties/subdomains. Currently, I can only view user flow for one property at a time.

Comment: You need to send all data to the same Web Property if you want to report on the Rollup

Comment: @Eduardo I created a web property and now have two tracking codes on the sub-domains I want to track. When I view behavior flow it says I may have applied an advanced condition for which there is no data. It's only been a day so far. Does this sound familiar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to track all subdomains in the same GA property and then send the subdomain along with each pageview as a content group value. Afterwards show the flow based on content grouping under "behaviour flow".

Comment: Please add some code so other users can test what you're describing. Thanks!